# Border On Screen Size 767px and Below Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm having some issue with a bootstrap site setup, for some reason when the window is smaller than 767px there is a 20px padding on the right and I have no idea how to get rid of it.

heres the site http://surf96.com/defaulttheme/

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sticky footer &middot; Twitter Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="img/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>


     <div id="wrap">
        <div  class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse"
                    data-toggle="collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class=
                    "icon-bar"></span></a>

                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">Menu</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">On Tap</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Shows</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Surfwear</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div><!-- container -->
            </div><!-- navbar-inner -->
        </div><!--  navbar navbar-fixed-top -->

        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Sticky footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Begin page content -->

    <div class="container">
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="muted credit">Example courtesy <a href=
            "http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href=
            "http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
        </div>
    <footer>


    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

typical bootstrap css and this for sticky footer.

```
/* Sticky footer styles
      -------------------------------------------------- */

      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
      }

      /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
      #wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
        margin: 0 auto -60px;
      }

      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      #push,
      footer {
        height: 60px;
      }
      footer {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        footer {
          margin-left: -20px;
          margin-right: -20px;
          padding-left: 20px;
          padding-right: 20px;
        }
      }


body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

Hope someone can help.

Denver

Comment: Hi @Denver, could you put your HTML code here? You must think that every question that a user makes in StackOverflow could be useful for other people. So when you solve your issue, your question will be useless, because the only HTML code we have is your link to the page.

Comment: Absolutely take a look at my update.

Comment: One of your problems is the `padding-top: 60px` of the body. Put `padding-top: 0`.

Comment: that is on purpose. Its the padding on the right that is the issue.

Denver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the space before the navbar, you have to delete one of the properties that you have set in your CSS:

```
.navbar .nav, .navbar .nav > li {
  float: none; <--
  ...
}
```

If you remove `float:none`, the menu will be aligned to the right.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the  `margin-right: -20px;` in the footer. 
This is causing the footer part to extend and create a scroll.

Here is the update:

```
footer {
    margin-left: -20px;
    /*margin-right: -20px;*/
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change following padding value to 0 in both bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css. Or you can override it in your custom css file.

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
}
```